# How does a Node.js server handle client connections and sockets?

Tags: node.js, sockets

I'm trying to understand how a Node.js server handles client connections and sockets. Specifically, I'm interested in knowing how the server creates and manages sockets for incoming client connections.

From my understanding, when a Node.js server starts and listens on a specific port (e.g., port 3000), it creates a listening socket. However, when a client connects to the server on the same port, does it create a new socket for each client connection?

I've seen examples where the server code includes event handlers for events like 'data', 'end', and 'error' on the socket object. But I'm unsure how these sockets are uniquely identified for each client and how the server knows which client to send the data back to.

Could someone explain the underlying process and mechanisms that allow a Node.js server to handle multiple client connections using sockets? How are sockets created, identified, and managed for incoming client connections?

Any insights, explanations, or examples would be greatly appreciated.

In below code, I see it logs different ports each time, why?

```
const net = require('net');

const server = net.createServer((socket) => {
  // This callback function is executed whenever a client connects
  console.log('Client connected');
 const clientPort = socket.remotePort;
  console.log(`Client port: ${clientPort}`);

});

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server listening on port 3000');
});

Output:
Server listening on port 3000
Client connected
Client port: 59414
Client connected
Client port: 59415
```

Comment: Yes, node.js servers are built on tcp, which has listening sockets and connection sockets. If you want to know more, you can read about tcp on wikipedia or other websites. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10861556/how-listening-to-a-socket-works